# Laravel Validator returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have two form pages which accept POST methods in my routing:

**web.php**

```
Route::post('select-room', ['as'=>'select-room','uses'=>'ClientBookingController@selectRoom']);
Route::post('book-room', ['as'=>'book-room','uses'=>'ClientBookingController@bookRoom']);
```

The functionality works as this. I submit data in page 'select-room' to 'book-room'

There is validation in methods 'selectRoom' and 'bookRoom'

```
public function selectRoom(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'start_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
            'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date',
            'number_people' => 'required', 
            'number_kids' => 'required'
        ]);
 }
 public function bookRoom(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'start_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
            'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date',
            'people' => 'required',
            'days_staying' => 'required',
            'free_days' => 'required',
            'room' => 'required|array',
            'roomCost' => 'required|array',
            'roomPeople' => 'required|array',
            'totalCost' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:255|confirmed'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
 }
```

When I submit the data and it does not validate in 'bookRoom' method the validation sends a get request and not a post request to 'select-room' url and I end up with a MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error.

I am still understanding Laravel is it possible that you cannot have a logical flow where you have a post page which then posts to another post page which if fails on the second post page will result in an error because your routing only allows post methods. Is the Validation functionality that restrictive that you must have a get request as a contingency for errors or is there something I may setup which can replicate the post request in the validation response set?

Comment: Any redirects are performed using GET. Your forms should be rendered as GET methods, and the data submitted as a POST request.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. Would it be possible to provide an example of this process lets say the 'selectRoom' method has processed the post how would there be a redirect to 'book-room' as a GET and how would I pass the data. I have researched but if you have any links I may reference to assist me with understanding this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `redirects` are performed using `GET`. Your forms should be `rendered` as `GET` methods, and the data `submitted` as a `POST` request. So make a new `URL` using get for the `book-room`.

```
Route::post('select-room', ['as'=>'select-room','uses'=>'ClientBookingController@selectRoom']);
Route::get('book-room', ['as'=>'book-room','uses'=>'ClientBookingController@showBookRoom']);
Route::post('book-room', ['as'=>'book-room','uses'=>'ClientBookingController@bookRoom']);
```

And in your controller-

```
public function selectRoom(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date',
        'number_people' => 'required', 
        'number_kids' => 'required'
    ]);
    // Validate data
    // Persist data ready for displaying book-room using get

    return redirect('book-room');
}
public function showBookRoom()
{
    return //your new view with post data from previous url
}
public function bookRoom(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'start_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date',
        'people' => 'required',
        'days_staying' => 'required',
        'free_days' => 'required',
        'room' => 'required|array',
        'roomCost' => 'required|array',
        'roomPeople' => 'required|array',
        'totalCost' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:255|confirmed'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
 }
```

So, whenever your second post `fails`, it will `redirect` to the intermediate `URL` using `GET` request. Read [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-back-to-post-route-i-get-methodnotallowed-exception) post from **Laracast**, you will have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question your select-room route method should be `any()` instead of `post()` then.

But there is something wrong with your flow. You should have a GET route  where you are displaying the select. A POST route where you are processing the POST data and go back to the GET route if you have errors.